# Identify some diodes?

Tags: diodes, identification

I have a small electronic board from a hand held snow plow controller.
The diode is cracked on one.

I would like to replace this component but want to make sure I get the correct one from digikey.
The hand controllers are very expensive and I would like to at least attempt to fix them before buying a new one.

[image: Cracked_Diode]
[image]

These other ones I just want to identify because I need additional ones that fell of the circuit board and are lost now.

[image: AdditionalDiode]

[image: AdditionalDiode2]

Comment: Can you zoom out a little bit on the first photo? If the designator for the diode is Z1, it could very well be a Zener diode, but no guarantee.

Comment: Added a second image from another angle.

Comment: Thank you. Some eCAD software uses Z designator for all diodes by default, but most don’t. The logo on it looks like ST.

Comment: your right!
STMicroelectronics

Comment: Others look like General Semiconductor and Diodes Inc logos.

Comment: Found 1! STMicroelectronics SMBJ15CA with marking BBG
Now to identify the other 2

Comment: These all look like TVS so the likely cause why they broke was a short circuit between V+ and ground. Or maybe feeding wrong current, or polarity swap etc. Have you found the actual cause? If not, they will just break again after you replace them - TVS popping is a symptom, not the error cause.

Comment: Yes the cause was a short to ground when the wiring harness was burned and the wires melted together

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 1st diode you already found yourself: [SMBJ15CA](https://www.mouser.ch/datasheet/2/389/cd00001366-1795574.pdf) from *STMicroelectronics*.

The 2nd diode is from a company formerly known as General Semiconductor.
[image]

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vishay_Intertechnology) *Vishay Intertechnology* has acquired *General Semiconductor* in 2001.

So the BM/2B could be [SMBJ15A](https://www.s-manuals.com/pdf/datasheet/s/m/smbj5.0a-smbj188a_vishay.pdf) from *Vishay Intertechnology*.

The 3rd diode: [S1GB-13-F](https://www.diodes.com/part/view/S1GB/) from *Diodes Incorporated*.

Datasheet: https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/ds16003.pdf

[image]